# How do I install Scribus stable release?

Tags: apt, software-installation, scribus

[Scribus installation guide for Ubuntu](https://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Debian) says that «the packages from the Debian and Ubuntu repositories are the standard way to obtain Scribus» and the [download page](https://www.scribus.net/downloads/stable-branch/) says that the current stable version is 1.4.8.

However, `sudo apt-get install scribus` installs version 1.5.6 (development), that is «for testing purposes only» (as advised in the splash screen) and indeed when I open it I can't even activate any button or menu item, so I want to install the stable version. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem but reinstalling and purging only solved it when I launched Scribus for the first time. The following launch always crashed.

I found the [corresponding bug in Scribus bug tracker](https://bugs.scribus.net/view.php?id=16295). It is not a Scribus bug apparently, but rather on Ubuntu's side.

I followed [one user's suggestion](https://bugs.scribus.net/view.php?id=16295#c48292) and it solved my problem :

In file `~/.config/scribus/scribus150.rc` you need to change the Maximized attribute of MainWindow element to "0" in the following line :

`<MainWindow Maximized="0" ScreenNumber="0" Height="1016" YPosition="27" XPosition="50" Width="1870"/>`

I still find it strange that the splashscreen says **1.5.6.svn** when the installed package is named **scribus/groovy,now 1.5.5+svn23928+dfsg-1build1 amd64  [installed]**...

Comment: The problems came back after some weeks of smooth working and I could only solve it with your solution. Strange things are happening here :)

Answer (score 1):

they also say (here : https://www.scribus.net/downloads/)

```
as of version 1.5.1, we consider the development branch reasonably stable, so it can be used for serious work by users who accept that not all *new* features are already working perfectly. 

Features *already available* in the officially stable version will work much better in 1.5.1+, though.
```

-> 1.5.5 should be stable enough for new features and old features even work better in 1.5.1+ than 1.4.6

it seems to me that 1.5.5 seems to be a reasonable choice

on my ubuntu 20.4 scribus 1.5.5 works OK

-- edit based on comment --

if there are still issues you can

remove ~/.config/scribus and reinstall scribus

```
sudo apt-get -y purge scribus
rm -fr ~/.config/scribus
sudo apt-get -y install scribus
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I had missed it! I purged scribus (`sudo apt-get purge scribus`, in case someone else needs it), remove its folders from `~/.config` and reinstalled it and now it works, no idea why.

Comment: @Ntakwetet did the purge solve definitely your problem ? I have the same issue on Ubuntu 20.10. Using apt to install Scribus it says that the package is 1.5.5 but once installed the splashcreen says it is 1.5.6 "for testint purposes only". I tried purge and reinstall but it solved the problem for the first launch only...

Comment: @raph I purged scribus, removed `~/.config/scribus` and reinstalled scribus. It is still version 1.5.6 "for testing purposes only", but now when I launch it I can use buttons and menus. I don't know hou much it really works as I'm still just looking around, but at least it looks usable.

Comment: Ok thanks. I posted an answer which solved my problem.